write encodings in Z3 Solver python for string functions like concat
write encodings in z3 solver python for string functions like concat, charAt, contains
Like for concat I have
formula= ForAll([fs1, fs2],
                            Implies(
                                And(Length(fs1) == l1, Length(fs2) == l2, concat == Concat(fs1, fs2)),
                                Length(concat) == l1 + l2
                            ))

But how can I omit the use of concat in this formula can someone explain

There can be many different ways of doing such an axiomatization. It all depends on what sort of "primitives" you are allowed to use. For instance, here is one way to axiomatize concat, assuming you're allowed to use SubString and Length:
from z3 import *

my_concat = Function('my_concat', StringSort(), StringSort(), StringSort())

def axiomatizeConcat (solver):
    s1   = FreshConst(StringSort())
    s2   = FreshConst(StringSort())
    ls1  = Length(s1)
    ls2  = Length(s2)
    ls   = ls1 + ls2
    res  = my_concat(s1, s2)
    sub1 = SubString(res, 0,   ls1)
    sub2 = SubString(res, ls1, ls2)
    solver.add(ForAll([s1, s2], And(Length(res) == ls, sub1 == s1, sub2 == s2)))

If you're not allowed SubString or Length, then you can axiomatize those similarly as well.
I should caution that such an axiomatization is unlikely to perform well in practice. Due to the quantified assertions you need, the solver will have very hard time deciding even the simplest equalities. For instance, if you try:
s = Solver()
axiomatizeConcat(s)

x = String("x")
s.add(x == my_concat(StringVal("Hello"), StringVal("World")))
print(s.sexpr())
print(s.check())
print(s.model())

you'll see that z3 fails to terminate. But the corresponding problem using the internal definition of Concat works just fine:
from z3 import *

s = Solver()

x = String("x")
s.add(x == Concat(StringVal("Hello"), StringVal("World")))
print(s.sexpr())
print(s.check())
print(s.model())

which prints:
(declare-fun x () String)
(assert (= x (str.++ "Hello" "World")))

sat
[x = "HelloWorld"]

But perhaps that's not what you're after and this is merely an exercise in modeling.
